# Is there any way to transfer data in C via RX/TX protocol?

Tags: c, arm, rxtx, tms570

I have a TMS570 processor and want to send data with RX/TX protocol but I want to code it in C.
Is there any way to code it and for the data,set a string to send?

Comment: What is Rx/Tx protocol? Do you mean serial?

Comment: yes,serial ports which can communicate with other sensors via rx/tx ports

Comment: this can help https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/hercules/f/312/t/565137?TMS570-using-UART-to-communicate-to-another-device

Comment: yes, there is a way, that is generally how it is done.

Comment: what did you find in the chip vendors libraries and examples for this chip/board?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer
I am using code composer studio which is the company that is producing the TMS570LS microcontrollers. It has some examples of C codes for rx/tx transferring data